# Site2Sms api from mashape.com

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write this as an async class and execute it like this:

```
new SendEmailAsyncTask().execute();
```

However, things doesn't seem to work. I have set a debug point at protected method class and even inside the method but debug doesn't reach till there.

Can you please help?

```
private class SendSMS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse<JsonNode>> {

    protected HttpResponse<JsonNode> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpResponse<JsonNode> request = null;
        try {
            // These code snippets use an open-source library.

            request = Unirest.get("https://site2sms.p.mashape.com/index.php?msg=hi+how+r+u-+from+site&phone=8861208777&pwd=password&uid=8861208777")
                    .header("X-Mashape-Key", "p3XaAQinTDmshBPYVDHF2EJgrZj1p1RcrrLjsnDrVCGxXDdQYd")
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .asJson();
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

       return request;
    }
}
```

---

Earlier, I have written the same in the main class and even that failed while it reaches .asJson call, and the debug points me to something like sCompatibiltyDone=true statement in View class. It doesn't even show me exception.

---

I could call the same service using Chrome Extension Advanced Rest client and with the same parameters. So I am thinking asJson didn't work from Android.

Libs contain - 
 activation.jar
 additionnal.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
httpasyncclient-4.0.2.jar
httpasyncclient-cache-4.0.2.jar
httpclient-4.3.6.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.6.jar
mail.jar
org.json.jar
unirest-java-1.4.5.jar

Comment: sCompatibilityDone = No such static field: 'sCompatibilityDone'
sIgnoreMeasureCache = No such static field: 'sIgnoreMeasureCache' in View.java

Comment: Kindly remove the key from the code, someone might misuse your key.