# Send SMS to mobile Using Java (Third Party-Site2SMS)

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, sms

I wrote the following code in `JAVA` to send a SMS to a mobile device using the free India-region web service [Site2SMS](http://site2sms.com/) site.  I'm authenticating via a key using the [Mashape Api](https://www.mashape.com/).

Soo here is my Code and Error MSG.

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class SendSMS
{
static String SMSApi = "https://site2sms.p.mashape.com/index.php?msg=Hello&phone=0987654321&pwd=abcdef&uid=XXXXXXXXXX";
static String head = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        String url = SMSApi;
        String smsApiResponse = sendMySMS(url);
        System.out.println(smsApiResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String sendMySMS(String url)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        URL hp = new URL(url);
        System.out.println(url);
        URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
        hpCon.setRequestProperty("X-Mashape-Key", head);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hpCon.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            output.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error response:

```js
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://site2sms.p.mashape.com/index.php?msg=Hello&phone=0987654321&pwd=abcdef&uid=1234567890

 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at SendSMS.sendMySMS(SendSMS.java:33)
 at SendSMS.main(SendSMS.java:15)
```

(The `Mashape` key, stored in `head` and the `uid` in the message url are obfuscated.)

Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong and how to correct my code?

Comment: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

`HTTP response code: 403` means forbidden, so it looks like an access issue.  I assume since it's `https` that you're missing some sort of login handshaking?

Comment: But my login id and pswrd is correct and all required params are there.. how can i solve it?? plz help me

Comment: I'm trying to help you by removing the personal / informal language from your post.  You will likely be downrated for that alone via many users in this community.  I see you undid my changes...  I advise against that. :)

Comment: Opps sorry.. I am new here so i thought It's done by site itself. so i did it... It's my mistake . I'll remind it in future. you can modify it if u want from now.. :)

Comment: Also shouldn't your property be `X-Mashape-Authorization` not `X-Mashape-Key`?  I'm unfamiliar with the Api, but that's what the latest documentation I found indicates: http://docs.mashape.com/javascript

Comment: Ya i have tried using **X-Mashape-Authorization** instead of **X-Mashape-Key** but still it gives the same error msg :(

Comment: Okay I cleaned up the question language and added some pertinent links.  For future reference, try to keep questions to the point without a lot of filler language like `Can someone bleh bleh bleh`  `Thank you so much bleh bleh bleh`... I can understand that's standard on other sites, but SO enforces a pretty strict code on wording questions formally and professionally.

Comment: Yes. I will remind it for any further questions. Thnx :)

Comment: Do you know for sure your key is good?  Also your `uid` looks made up.... shouldn't you have the `uid` as a class variable?

Comment: Ya it's valid **API key**. and **uid** and **password** are also valid for **Site2SMS**. Without using **uid** as class variable m using it directly.

Comment: Your `uid` is really `1234567890`?! ... that seems improbable.  :0

Comment: No no. It's just for privacy reason I didn't provide my original uid,password,api here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935880/site2sms-api-from-mashape-com

Comment: Thanks but It's not that much helpful for me :/

Comment: Other resources indicate that the Api outputs a message with its 403 errors with more details (Google site2sms api for examples).  I don't see that above.  Try printing that as it may describe what is going on.